# Is it safe to remove @SynoEAStream empty files on Synology NAS?

Tags: synology-diskstation

I wonder what generates theses `@eaDir` directories all over the Synology NAS shares filesystem.

I need to clean up empty files on a Synology NAS.

Is it safe to remove `@eaDir/*@SynoEAStream` empty files ?

Or even better can I remove theses `@eaDir` directories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are created by the Indexer (they are hidden files/folders, so if it's simply annoying to see, and you want the Indexer enabled, then set it to not show hidden files.)

You can disable the indexer if you want.

It's certainly safe to remove those directories, they'll just reappear if the Indexer is still enabled.

Comment: Is this indexer used when accessing the data through a SMB/NFS/rsync shares ?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it, it's only used for "*multimedia packages such as Synology Photos, Video Station, Audio Station, Media Server, and iTunes Server*" (see https://kb.synology.com/en-eu/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/application_mediaindexservice_general?version=7)